# Group by datetime field but ignore only seconds

Tags: c#

I have list of objects. Every object has `DateTime` field:

```
Name   Date
A      2018-01-01 10:00:00   (1)
A      2018-01-01 10:00:00   (2)
A      2018-01-01 10:01:03   (3)
A      2018-01-01 10:01:22   (4)
B      2018-01-01 10:00:00   (5)
B      2018-01-01 10:00:02   (6)
```

I want to get list without duplicates, so I do:

```
list.GroupBy(g => new {g.Name, g.Date}).Select(d => d.First())
                .OrderBy(d => d.Date).ToList();
```

The query works fine, but now I want to get records unique if they have different date, hours and minutes. So, for the example above, I want to get the following records:

```
Name   Date
A      2018-01-01 10:00:00   (1)
A      2018-01-01 10:01:03   (3)
B      2018-01-01 10:00:00   (5)
```

I wanted to format `Date` to some string without seconds:

```
g.Date.ToString("g")
```

But, it's not possible because

> The anonymous type projection initializer should be simple name or member expression.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Try `new {g.Name, Date = g.Date.AddSeconds(-g.Date.Second)}`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled this is what happens when you have not used C# for a while :). Thanks. Write answer please, I will mark it,

Comment: Done. Now you see why I've started out with a comment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create anonymous types by simply declaring `new {}` and specify properties of known types, the property names of the anonymous type are copied from the property names in its declaration.
When you specify values or methods, the c# compiler can't infer the names of the anonymous type properties, so you need to specify them.

Also, please note that `DateTime.ToString("g");` will return a string representing the date, and its format is dictated by the current culture. 
From [Microsoft's Standard Date and Time Format Strings, The General Date Short Time ("g") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-general-date-short-time-g-format-specifier):

> The result string is affected by the formatting information of a specific DateTimeFormatInfo object. The following table lists the DateTimeFormatInfo object properties that may control the formatting of the returned string. The custom format specifier that is returned by the DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern and DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortTimePattern properties of some cultures may not make use of all properties.

So instead of dealing with string representations, it's better to simply return a new instance of `DateTime` with its seconds set to 0 - the easy way to do it is `dateTimeInstance.AddSeconds(-dateTimeInstance.Second)`.
And as Evk noted in the comments - you need to also set the milliseconds to 0  the same way - `dateTimeInstance.AddMilliseconds(-dateTimeInstance.Millisecond)`

So, to incorporate all that into your code:

```
list.GroupBy(
    g => new 
    {
        g.Name, 
        Date = g.Date.AddSeconds(-g.Date.Second).AddMilliseconds(-g.Date.Millisecond)
    }).Select(d => d.First())
    .OrderBy(d => d.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: You need to also set milliseconds to 0, otherwise grouping will be incorrect unless all times somehow have whole number of seconds.

Comment: @Evk correct, thanks! I've edited that into my answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @shim Thanks for the syntax corrections. English is not my native language.

Comment: @user348173 Glad to help :-)

Comment: maybe easier ` Date = new DateTime(g.Date.Year, g.Date.Month, G.Date.Day, g.Date.Hour, g.Date.Minute, 0)`

Comment: with easier I meant "not subjctet to forget to subtract milliseconds". but they both work and are easy to understand, so, just a matter of preference